# PWM control (Rosbot 2.0)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'd like to know how to control the PWM signal directly.
The motor is controlled by cmd_vel by using ros node but how to control the PWM without cmd_vel msg?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389035/pwm-control-(rosbot-2.0)/) by [choking](https://answers.ros.org/users/85763/choking/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-10-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Rosbot 2.0 uses an ASUS Tinker board for low level control. You have the ability to read PWM from the servos but you can also interact with the firmware via rosservice to set PWM: https://github.com/husarion/rosbot-stm32-firmware

```
$ rosservice call /config "command: 'CSER'
>data: 'V:0 S:1 E:1 P:20000 W:1000 '"
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choking](https://answers.ros.org/users/85763/choking/) on 2021-10-24**:
I'm already read the material  But I want to control the DC motor for the wheels.
Can I have any information for DC motor control for Rosbot 2.0?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-10-24**:
Just connect to the hbridge of the core2

https://husarion.com/manuals/core2/

**Comment by [choking](https://answers.ros.org/users/85763/choking/) on 2021-10-24**:
Thank you, sir.
I will try it!